# NHibernate ICriteria returns null

Tags: c#, wcf, nhibernate

I'm trying to create a wcf services that is connected to a database. For the connection I am using NHibernate. Here is the class Course that also is mapped in the file **rsultMngSystmMapper.hbm.xml**:

```
[DataContract]
public class Course
{
    private int ccode;
    private string cname;
    private int credits;

    [DataMember]
    public int CCode
    {
        get
        {
            return ccode;
        }
        set
        {
            ccode = value;
        }
    }
   etc...
}
```

Every property(with both getter and setter) in the above class has the attribute DataMember. Now the file rsultMngSystmMapper.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="RManageSystemService"
                   namespace="RManageSystemService.orm_rman_systm">
  <class name="Course" table="Courses" lazy="false">
    <id name="CCode" column="ccode">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="CName" column="cname"/>
    <property name="Credits" column="credit"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now the file hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=Mnemonics;User ID=Mnmncs;Password=mnmncs;Initial Catalog=database-name;Integrated Security=true</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping assembly="RManageSystemService"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Should I put the above code in the web.config instead? Or is it okay to have it separated?

Now the class RMngrDataManipulation:
This is the only method in this class by now:

```
public static Course RetrieveData(Course c)
{
    Configuration myConfig;
    ISessionFactory mySessFac;
    ISession mySess;
    myConfig = new Configuration();
    myConfig.Configure(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "hibernate.cfg.xml"));
    mySessFac = myConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
    mySess = mySessFac.OpenSession();
    try
    {
        ICriteria criteria = mySess.CreateCriteria<Course>();
        IList<Course> cList = criteria.List<Course>();
        foreach (Course course in cList)
        {
            c = course;
        }
        //This one is empty
        return c;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!mySessFac.IsClosed)
        {
            mySessFac.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The result I get when I invoke the method **RetrieveData()** from class **CourseService.svc.cs** in WCF Test Client is the following

[image]

Is there anything I have missed? Is my mapping file correct? I would be very thankful for some inputs from you guys.

EDIT: Looking at the output tab in VS2012 I find this message: A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

EDIT2(27.12.2014, 17.51)

> could not execute query [ SELECT this_.ccode as ccode2_0_, this_.cname as cname2_0_, this_.credit as credit2_0_ FROM Courses this_ ] [SQL: SELECT this_.ccode as ccode2_0_, this_.cname as cname2_0_, this_.credit as credit2_0_ FROM Courses this_] Server stack trace: vid System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter) vid System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) vid System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) vid System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) vid System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) Exception rethrown at [0]: vid System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) vid System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) vid IServiceManager.RetrieveData() vid ServiceManagerClient.RetrieveData()

Comment: Can you post the entire exception?

Comment: Did you set your mapping file as Embedded Resource?

Comment: @MrMush Now I did. Would you like to see my edited question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the fact, that this statement: **`foreach (Course course in cList)`** is doing nothing, i.e. the `cList` is **`empty`** - I'd suspect the wrong mapping file. Well...

1) One think could be, that `rsultMngSystmMapper.hbm.xml` is not properly marked as **`Embedded Resource`**. Check the properties of that file and its *`Build Action`*

2) The mapping file is in different library then the POCO objects. The setting says: `<mapping assembly="RManageSystemService"/>` and because the POCO is in is for sure in this library, it could be that your mapping files are in some other, e.g. **`RManageSystemService.Data`**

One of these "wrong" settings of the mapping file could be the culprit.

> NHibernate does behave a bit weird, if we ask for a criteria for **NOT** mapped entity/object. It simply returns empty list at the end, without any message or exception...

Comment: Actually all of them was wrong. 1-rsultMngSystmMapper.xml was marked as Content instead of Embedded Resource 2-my mapping file was in a sub-folder called mapper. I dragged it out from the sub-folder. Now I get another error message. Please look my edit.

Comment: I would say, that this is a big progress, just the exception... is not full I'd say. DO not have you more details? The good is: your mapping is now visible for NHibernate! great;) nice to see that all these settings did that. NHiberante was even able to create SQL ... but then ... Exception is usually clear.. but in this case is missing something. If you try to execute the **SELECT this_.ccode as ccode2_0_, this_.cname as cname2_0_, this_.credit as credit2_0_ FROM Courses this_** on your DB engine... is it working? returning results?

Comment: yeah that was exactly what I was thinking to do. The error was that I had inserted wrong column name in the mapping file. Instead of having credits, I had credit. But thanks to you I decreased a 5 hours job to 10 minutes. :) Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Great to see that sir! ;) also, I would suggest: do not use lazy="false" and make all your C# properties virtual (to support proxy)... good luck with NHibernate ;) great tool ;)